# Guardar coordendas XY en una lista por filas

Tags: python, python-3.x

Quiero guardar una serie de valores en una lista (coordenadas XY de diferentes puntos). Yo se obtener los puntos e incluso guardarlos en una lista, el problema es que se me guardan con el siguiente formato:

```
COORDS : (175, 303, 177, 335, 182, 368)
```

Y yo querría algo visualmente así:

```
COORDS :(175, 303,
         177, 335,
         182, 368)
```

Y es que así cada fila representa a las coordenadas X (primera columna) e Y (segunda columna) de mis puntos previamente obtenido. A continuación muestro mi último intento:

```
puntos = (1,2,3)
coords = ()
for punto in puntos:
    coords = coords + (landmarks.part(punto).x, landmarks.part(punto).y)

print('COORDS',':', coords)
```

¿Cómo debería escribirlo para conseguir mi objetivo? Mi idea no es modficar el print, si no la tupla, si no me equivoco sería pasarla a dos dimensiones.

¡Salud y gracias!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NEA, como no incluiste los **import** de tu código, no pude probarlo, pero podrías cambiar la variable **coords** de tupla a lista, y anexar a ella, con **append**, una tupla con las  coordenadas que quieres:

```
puntos = (1,2,3)
coords = []
for punto in puntos:
    coords.append((landmarks.part(punto).x, landmarks.part(punto).y))

print('COORDS',':', coords)
```

Comment: Gracias, ya lo solucioné pero me había olvidado ponerlo aquí. Hice exactamente esto jajaja.

Answer (score 0):

Este print te puede alinear tus coordenadas

```
print('COORDS:({0},{1},\n{2:>11},{3},\n{4:>11},{5})'.format(*COORDS))
```

Aqui hago un salto de linea "\n" cada dos números, hago una alineación de 11 espacios a la derecha ">" de estas líneas, con *COORDS se desempaca la tupla para que corresponda con los 6 elementos.

Hay muchas más variantes.

Si necesitas hacer más formateos te recomiendo esta respuesta en inglés donde exponen diferentes librerias para hacerlo más cómodo.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/26937531/8512548